# How can I import integers from Mysql as dates in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

Here is the sample data in MySQL as it is shown in the image[my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7jqR.png)

Both trade_date and trade_time are integers.
In DolphinDB, I used the following script to create the database:

```
monthDB = database(,VALUE, 1990.01M..2050.12M)
tickDB = database(, HASH, [SYMBOL, 20])
db = database("dfs://minute_price", COMPO, [monthDB, tickDB])
columns = `trade_date`trade_time`secu_code`int_code`code_type`open`close`high`low`volume`turnover
types = [DATE,TIME,SYMBOL,INT,INT,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE,DOUBLE]
db.createPartitionedTable(table(10:0, columns, types), `price_data,`trade_date`secu_code)
```

I used the following script to convert trade_date into date type, and trade_time into time type:

```
schema=select name,type from extractSchema(conn,`quote_1m)
update schema set type="TIME" where name="trade_time"
update schema set type="DATE" where name="trade_date"
mysql::loadEx(conn, db,`quote_1m, `trade_date`secu_code, schema);
```

It returned an error message “Couldn’t convert from INT to DATE”.
Any ideas? I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script:

```
db=database("dfs://minute_price")
query="select date(trade_date) as date, time(trade_time) as time, secu_code,int_code,code_type,open,close,high,low,volume,turnover from trades"
mysql::loadEx(conn, db, "price_data", `trade_date`secu_code, query);
```